# python webscraping: You don't have permission to access this resource

Tags: python, selenium, headless

I need to **scrape** a site in "headless" format, because I don't want to see the window popping up.
The code below works if the site is visible, but doesn't work as headless, showing I have no permission:

"Access Denied

You don't have permission to access "http://www.hoteis.com/ho402825/?" on this server.

Reference #18.563106c9.1620956860.1bad747"

The code is:

```
    def search():
            link = (
            https://www.infomoney.com.br/
            )

            chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
            chrome_options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
            chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
            driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver', options = chrome_options)
            driver.get(link)
            element = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body')
            resposta = element.get_attribute('innerHTML') 
            site = BeautifulSoup(resposta, 'html.parser')
            return driver, site
```

I saw some questions saying to apply 'headers' on my code, but as I'm using the webdriver, I think it doesn't work.

```
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0'}
```

Comment: FYI it’s __scrape__ (and __scraping__, __scraper__, __scraped__) not scrap. ‘To scrap’ means to throw away like rubbish.

Comment: As a note, be aware that its illegal to scrape some websites in this method--Always check the "robots.txt" file of a website before scraping it (you can add this into your code easily to automate it) It also may be possible that the site is recognizing (when you run it headless) that your script is a robot, and it may be kicking it out because of that, but I don't know enough about this subject to say that with confidence.

Answer (score 0):

Any idea if the site(s) you are attempting to scrape allow this action?

find any websites scraping rules at:
any `www.site.com/robots.txt`

EX:

[www.google.com](https://www.google.com)

[www.google.com/robots.txt](http://www.google.com/robots.txt)

[www.facebook.com](http://www.facebook.com)

[www.facebook.com/robots.txt](http://www.facebook.com/robots.txt)

robots.txt help:

https://www.infocompile.com/how-to-view-robots-txt-file-of-any-website/

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to scrape entire web page in headless mode, there are lot of ways. you call use the below css selector for body tag and use 'outerHTML' attribute.

**Code :**

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('start-maximized')
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\etc\\Desktop\\Selenium+Python\\chromedriver.exe", options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
driver.get("https://www.infomoney.com.br/")
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("body[class^='home page-template-default page page-id-']")
resposta = element.get_attribute('outerHTML')
print(resposta)
site = BeautifulSoup(resposta, 'html.parser')
```